# Powershell script indent

Tags: 2013, powershell

Please I want to reformat the power shell script as we did in visual studio,

can any one suggest me the good editor to do this ?

```
if ()
  {

}
```

indent script

```
if ()
 {

 }
```

Comment: Use visual studio code with power shell extension https://code.visualstudio.com

Comment: please share the full url of extension

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell