# remove account from managed account issue

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, managed-account

when i try to delete a managed account through central admin

> sorry, something went wrong the account is still being used by a
>   application pool : name

I changed the application pool identity in iis to another account and no luck, i can't delete the account from managed account!

I tried to restart SPTimer, and IIS and restart server no luck :(
I have tried removing the account from PS using the remove-spmanagedaccount ,i got : The account domain\user is still being used by these component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make sure this account is not being used by sharepoint.For this

- go to central admin > security > Configured the managed accounts
- On this page, click Edit button infront of the service account you are trying to delete
- next page, look bottom of the page and it will list all the apppool or services where this ID is being used.
- Now you have to change id for that apppool / service from SharePoint not directly from IIS. then reset IIS and try again.

Comment: yes i did , no luck , in farm components using this account show one app pool , I changed the application pool identity in iis to another account. and iis reset performed then restart server no luck,

Comment: did you change it from sharepoint not from IIS? cenral admin > security > configure the service account. from here select app pool and then change the id from last drop down.

Comment: I'm sorry why this question on hold https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/214782/powershell-script-indent could you help me ?

Comment: i think it is not directly related to SharePoint that's why...You can ask the same question over here" http://stackoverflow.com/questions" that is more programming forum...this is sharepoint forum.

Comment: I asked about SharePoint power shell please Do you know how can i reformat my script??

Comment: Honestly, i am not coding guru...But i always use Windows PwoerShell ISE.

Comment: check this one https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AdamRDriscoll.PowerShellToolsforVisualStudio2015